# Why am I getting an OData BadRequest_MethodNotImplemented error with business central using a complex expression as a filter?

Tags: odata, dynamics-business-central

Using OData with Business Central (22.2) I'm trying to get a result using the following filter:
`&$filter=description+eq+%27%40*ca+cu*%27+or+(description+eq+%27%40*ca*%27)+and+(description+eq+%27%40*cut*%27)`
My goal with this is to get a result that either contains the string 'ca cu' or contains both of these strings 'ca' and 'cu'. However I'm getting met with the following error

```
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_MethodNotImplemented",
        "message": "The OData filter expression is not supported.  CorrelationId:  ..."
    }
```

I've tried implementing both parts of the expression seperately like this:
`&$filter=(description+eq+%27%40*ca*%27)+and+(description+eq+%27%40*cut*%27)`
`&$filter=description+eq+%27%40*ca+cu*%27`
Like this it seems to work fine. However when I try the expression combined it seems to not work.

What I am confused about is that this limit isn't described in the official Microsoft documentation:
[Odata Known Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/odata-known-limitations)

So my question is, is using complex expressions in BC 22.2 OData queries limited. If this is the case what would my best course of action be? Use two queries to get the exact results or would another approach be better?